# Selenium Grid 2 Jenkins CI automation Single sign on application

Tags: selenium, jenkins, grid, continuous-integration

I am currently working on an application which has single sign on. You have to be logged in using the LAN or internal wireless Network to access the web page. My architecture team has created the Jenkin Job with Selenium Grid for the automation.

We have Jenkins slave created on a remote server. Now, when I try to run my tests, I get the error message and the tests does not run. But when I run the http://www.google.com page, the tests run successfully. Has anyone faced this issue before?

Comment: Have you tried the Selenium IDE (from firefox only) http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/ to record the steps to single sign on (first removing cookies). You can then save the steps out in a variety of languages.

Comment: The Tests I have runs on my local machines. Since I am already logged on on the network, I donot need to provide username and password. I have been running my Tests using maven.